# Problema con Excepciones dentro de constructor

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo una clase, que extiende de JPanel, que en su **constructor** llama a un método **que puede lanzar dos tipos de Excepciones**:

```
class Panel extends JPanel{
    //...
    public Panel(){
        //...
        metodQuePuedLanzExcep();//última linea del contructor
    }
    private void metodQuePuedLanzExcep(){
        try{
            //todo el codigo dentro del try
            //...
            if(talCondicion) throw new MiExcepcion();
            //luego vienen las lineas de codigo donde se
            //puede producir el NullPointerException
            unalista.size();//precisamente
            //...
        }
        catch(MiExcepcion eMiEx){
        }
        catch(NullPointerException eNulPoinEx){
        }

    }
}
```

O sea, **esa última linea del constructor** no se va a ejecutar si se produce una excepción, y las excepciones son bien capturadas (mensaje correspondiente),  pero **se produce un error en el Panel**(no se visualizan los componentes).

Lo raro es que no debería pasar ya que **metodQuePuedLanzExcep()** lo que hace es llenar filas a una tabla, por lo tanto si no se ejecuta, la tabla se debería mostrar, solo que vacía.

En resumen, al producirse la excepción me desecha todas las lineas de código (constructor) que están antes de llamar a ese método.
No estaré controlando correctamente las excepciones o será que dentro del 
constructor se hace de otra forma, no sé nada de excepciones.

> Entonces ¿cómo hacer para que a pesar de la excepción el constructor
>   Panel() siga su curso normal?

Comment: Parece muy poca información para poder ayudarte. Si pudieras poner el código completo de la clase Panel podría ser más fácil encontrar el error.

Comment: Lo hice así por que era un poco extenso y por lo general cuando es así nadie responde. De todas formas voy a buscar en mi programa esa parte del código, que ahora no recuerdo ni en que parte está, tampoco recuerdo como lo solucioné, pero seguramente que fue una solución a medias para salir del paso jaj. Igualmente es medio raro no? O sea si capturo la excepción se supone que el programa debe seguir su curso, no? ¿O la "excepción a la regla" es cuando se produce dentro de un constructor ?

Comment: Cuando capturas una excepción se interrumpe el flujo del programa y se ejecuta lo que tengas en el bloque del catch y despues lo que tengas en el bloque finally, si lo incluyeras en el programa.